# jQuery: не записывает в значение переменной значение поля ввода

Tags: javascript, jquery

Такое поле ввода:

```
<input type="text" name="admin_id">
```

С помощью jQuery я благополучно получаю значение этого поля, но в переменную оно записываться не хочет. Привожу диалог из косоли Chrome:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё у вас записывается, просто вас консоль запутала. Если вкратце, то `var a = 100` - это конструкция. Такая же конструкция, как и, скажем, `if (true) {}`. Конструкции всегда возвращают `undefined` и их нельзя использовать в выражениях, т.к. это приведет к синтаксической ошибке. Например, `console.log(var a = 100)` выведет ошибку.

А, например, `a = 100` (без `var`) - это выражение, которое возвращает результат выполнения (в данном примере - число 100). И выражения можно использовать внутри других выражений, например `console.log(a = 100)`.

Подробно об этом можно почитать [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844840/why-does-javascript-variable-declaration-at-console-results-in-undefined-being).

[image: Скриншот консоли]